# Performing text processing on flatpage content to include handling of custom tag

Tags: python, django, algorithm, text-processing

I'm using flatpages app in my project to manage some html content. That content will include images, so I've made a `ContentImage` model allowing user to upload images using admin panel.
The user should then be able to include those images in content of the flatpages. He can of course do that by manually typing image url into `<img>` tag, but that's not what I'm looking for.

To make including images more convenient, I'm thinking about something like this:

- User edits an additional, let's say `pre_content` field of `CustomFlatPage` model (I'm using custom flatpage model already)
- instead of defining `<img>` tags directly, he uses a custom tag, something like `[img=...]` where `...` is name of the `ContentImage` instance
- now the hardest part: before `CustomFlatPage` is saved, `pre_content` field is checked for all `[img=...]` occurences and they are processed like this:
- `ContentImage` model is searched if there's image instance with given name and if so, `[img=...]` is replaced with proper `<img>` tag.
- flatpage actual `content` is filled with processed `pre_content` and then flatpage is saved (`pre_content` is leaved unchanged, as edited by user)

The part that I can't cope with is text processing. Should I use regular expressions? Apparently they can be slow for large strings.
And how to organize logic? I assume it's rather algorithmic question, but I'm not familliar with text processing in Python enough, to do it myself.

Can somebody give me any clues?

Comment: I like that. Normally the answer is: "don't use regex, use html parser", but what about custom tags? I'd like to know as well

Comment: PS: `BeautifulSoup` is an awesome HTML parsing library. If you're willing to look at the source, I'm sure that would be a fantastic resource. It's king at processing even broken html. I'm starting to think regex might be ok for your tags though, since it does not involve closing tag complexity but a few possible variations of `[img=]` `[ img = ]`

Comment: Thanks. I'll look at this `BeautilfulSoup` source. Maybe I'd be able to borrow some ideas from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally imlemented this using regular expressions. I decided, that spaces are not allowed inside the custom tag. Main text processing function looks like this:

```
import re
from django.utils.translation import ugettext as _

def process_image_tags(text, ImageModel):
    '''image tag usage:
        ... some text ... [img=image_name:image_class(optional)] ... some text ...
    '''
    t1 = re.split(r'(\[img=[a-z0-9\-_\:]+\])', text)
    t2 = []
    for i in t1:
        if i[:5] == '[img=':
            attrs = i[5:-1].split(':')
            name_attr = attrs[0] #name attribute
            error = None
            try:
                image = ImageModel.objects.get(name=name_attr)
            except ImageModel.DoesNotExist:
                error = '<span class="image_tag_error">%s</span>' % _('Image with given name not found')
            except ImageModel.MultipleObjectsReturned:
                error = '<span class="image_tag_error">%s</span>' % _('More than one image found')
            if not error:
                p = ['<img']
                p.append('src="%s"' % image.image.url) 
                if len(attrs) > 1:
                    p.append('class="%s"' % attrs[1]) #class attribute
                if image.description:
                    p.append('title="%s"' % image.description)
                p.append('alt="%s"' % image.name)
                p.append('/>')                   
                t2.append(' '.join(p))
            else:
                t2.append(error)
        else:
            t2.append(i)
    return ''.join(t2)
```

Above function is then used in save method of `CustomFlatPage` model, like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):           
    self.content = process_image_tags(self.pre_content, ContentImage)        
    super(CustomFlatPage, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

It seems to work, so I'll probably end up using that solution. Maybe I'll add some javascript for user to insert image tags by picking images from generated list of images, but even now it's better than manually typing urls, I think.

Comment: I notice you don't add an `alt` attribute. You might as well, using  `image.name`

Comment: @JordanReiter Yes, why not, thanks :-). I just added it to the code.